# Onedrive Rest API error: 400 Bad Request when getting children

Tags: office365, onedrive

API: https://appstaging-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drive/root/children

Error: 400 bad request

Response header:
+                            Headers               {Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
X-SP-SERVERSTATE: ReadOnly=0
ODATA-VERSION: 4.0
SPClientServiceRequestDuration: 139
SPRequestGuid: a4ba8e9d-205d-3000-b030-6297e392605f
request-id: a4ba8e9d-205d-3000-b030-6297e392605f
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 16.0.0.5423
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private
Date: Mon, 11 Jul 2016 10:25:23 GMT
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
}              System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpResponseHeaders

Request header:
+                            Headers               {Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ik1uQ19WWmNBVGZNNXBPWWlKSE1iYTlnb0VLWSIsImtpZCI6Ik1uQ19WWmNBVGZNNXBPWWlKSE1iYTlnb0VLWSJ9.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.FjT6qfq-GGXxWVGVsa4NoHVBykAkGDuwWaDKlK7x2kStZgnAPCkBin3icaO7HXKvne2Dkp72jAvGwFEpN30yB4TJoThGmNLgFWmpWoBvx9w_A6kuPTUWRV9jr9wvBdtCLgDzXlxOSVZBZYfa9yDDapGqRMm_jkwep5dOlqlsAAFE7Flt7WFQYEUAX3yp50ecwQJIHLC2sVOz7bFe67I2PMmgqFKZaZrpchHwD3L4c1tm7Vkme86dl3vNySlA1OMjGqEve1dcAlAQF7nfoaoURDRlItpADGtHOF4SzkpRQzxH2CaforW6wsYO5ajFj1F1IKIqxFca3MlQnUEwoB8TfQ
Accept: application/json
}              System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpRequestHeaders

Comment: I suggest that you use the **Fiddler** to track the detail error message. And can you login the SharePoint site `https://appstaging-my.sharepoint.com` to ensure it exits?

Comment: Is this a new issue (i.e. has it worked for you in the past)? If it's new, is it consistent or do you find it sometimes work and sometimes doesn't?

Comment: It was working fine before in the past. I had discussion with MS support team and this issue was from their end and now its solved. Thanks